# React: TypeError not a function while calling a function using ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Problem**

Issue that I am facing is when I call ref.current.close() I get an error stating _ref$current.close is not a function

```
type ComponentElement = HTMLDivElement & { close: () => void; open: () => void }

const Component = () => {
   const ref = useRef<ComponentElement>()
   console.log("Ref", ref.current)
   return (
     <ChildComponent ref={ref}>
        <Button
          primary
          color={action.color}
          hoverIndicator={{
            color: action?.color,
            opacity: 'medium'
          }}
          label={action.label}
          onClick={() => {
            ref.current?.close()
           }}
        />
     </ChildComponent>
  )
 }
```

**Debug Result**

Till now as much as I can see it seems there is something to do with the initialisation of the ref

[image]

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the **implementation** of `ChildComponent`, since that would (or won't) provide a `close` method.

Comment: On the face of it, it seems like that should work given that console output (**please** replace or augment the image with text; [why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247)). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Trying to do what you are asking for actually the child component implementation is huge so will need some time to do it

Comment: If you haven't already, please do read through the [mcve] link. But I'm assuming that you've already read that and it's reducing the "huge" component to a reasonable MRE that will take time. (It's not entirely clear why that would be, though; seems like it shouldn't take long to strip out everything other than the `close` method and minimal parts of the `render` method.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually its taking time to strip because the child component is not in the same project its from a component library - https://v2.grommet.io/layer

Comment: That would be hard. :-) I don't see a `close` method documented on the `Layer` component, though. In fact, I don't see any `close` method documented [anywhere in that lib](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22close%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fv2.grommet.io). Is it documented somewhere I've missed? If not, why are you trying to call it?

Comment: Actually I did a hard fork on that library and modified it for my project. So added some functions which I need. So give me some more time so I can figure out a way to make it work in a very simplified way. Apologies for the delay!

Comment: No worries. :-) But just for the avoidance of doubt: If the component had a `close` method at the point where you're trying to use it, that code would work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yxxddm?file=src/App.js So the real issue here is that the component doesn't seem to have one (at that point).